# Gnus fails opening larger imap group

Tags: debugging, gnus, imap

If I try to open an larger imap group (a few thousand messages both read and unread) Gnus gives a warning:
Wrong number of arguments: #, 2
And the Summary window is empty or it contains only some of the messages.

*Compile Log* shows:
Warning: ‘not’ called with 2 args, but requires 1

If I limit the number of messages to fetch to e.g. 200 (C-u RET) it works fine. Limiting to 500 triggers the same warning.

The problem shows up with different imap servers, both for emacs 26 and 27.
The gnus config is fairly basic, just nnimap sources with gnus-secondary-select-methods and gnus-posting-styles.

*imap log* shows:
23:56:34 [poczta.agh.edu.pl] 122 UID FETCH 107408,107410,107415,107424:107425,107431,107448:107449,107453,107463,107469:107470,107472:107473,107489,107495,107511,107519,107522,107524,107526:107542,107545:107547,107549:107553,107559:107561,107564,107569:107573,107576,107580,107586,107592,107594:107595,107629,107635:107638,107652:107655,107661,107664,107689,107695,107698:107699,107702,107706,107711,107716:107717,107723,107732,107746,107752:107755,107757,107773,107775,107779....,111987,111999:112015,112017:112050 (UID RFC822.SIZE BODYSTRUCTURE BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (Subject From Date Message-Id References In-Reply-To Xref To Newsgroups Cc)])

Any thoughts on how to fix it or what's wrong?

Comment: `(setq debug-on-error t)`, reproduce the issue, then use `M-x report-emacs-bug` , insert the backtrace, send to the Emacs developers.

Answer (score 1):

It was my badly formed sort function. I had:

(setq gnus-thread-sort-functions
'(not gnus-thread-sort-by-most-recent-date))

which should be:

(setq gnus-thread-sort-functions
'((not gnus-thread-sort-by-most-recent-date)))

Comment: If you accept your own answer, stackexchange will stop reminding us about your question :-)